# Why Fertilisation occurs only in Fallopian tube?

Tags: reproduction, sexual-reproduction

The Ova is released and stops in the fallopian tube for the sperm..The Fertilisation occurs at the Fallopian tube, but as the zygote divides and forms an embryo, it attaches to the lining of uterus.But why doesn’t the egg come to the uterus and the fertilisation occur in Uterus?? Simply,Why cannot the site of fertilisation be the Uterus?

Comment: Welcome to the site. What research have you done on your own to answer this question? The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Our goal is not simply to be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way.

Comment: Hello Respected Sir! I’m a 14yr old Student..These subjects are out of my syllabus.But Still, I Would like to learn each topic, but to learn i have to ask questions. I Have gathered only this information regarding this.I Know you are helping me in a way to learn something myself.But I Would like to ask these questions so that i can self learn. I Don’t simply come to SE community and asks questions, i search the questions or info in google or youtube, when there is no help, i just ask here.
I’m Sorry, If I’m Hurting you! But I’m just a beginner and there are many other students in SE Like me!!

Comment: good for you for being curious! By previous research, I mean what did you learn when you took the title of your question and [asked it on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+Fertilisation+occurs+only+in+Fallopian+tube%3F)? What resources there helped? What are you still confused about? Essentially, the answer is that Fallopian tubes evolved to be the place where fertilization occurs in humans, and the uterus did not evolve to be very conducive to fertilization; rather, it is good for implantation and growth.